# Is there a real difference between dynamic analysis and testing?

Tags: testing, dynamic-analysis

Often testing is regarded as a dynamic analysis of a software. Yet while writing my thesis, the reviewer noted to me that dynamic analysis is about analyzing the program behind the scenes - e.g. profiling and that it is not the same as testing because its "analysis" which looks inside and observes.
I know that "static analysis" is not testing, should we then separate this "dynamic analysis" also from testing? Some books do refer to dynamic analysis in this sense. I would maybe say that testing is a one mean of dynamic analysis?

As for testing definitions:

> IEEE 829 broadens the idea to “analyzing,” thus including “static
>   testing.” And ISTQB takes the full step and includes both “dynamic and
>   static.” Testing is both dynamic and static.

So maybe it is just a matter of semantics? If testing is considered to be an analysis, then its both static and dynamic analysis is a testing approach.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a good analogy is that (manual) testing is to dynamic analysis what code reviews are to static analysis. Both manual testing and dynamic analysis rely on the behaviour of code as it is executed to find problems.

But testing is not a means for dynamic analysis. For starters, dynamic analysis is automated. It also helps you observe behaviours that are not easily seen otherwise, such as memory usage and profiling. Testing, on the other hand, helps you assess qualities like usability and presentation, things you cannot ask a dynamic analysis tool to help you with.

Comment: Hmm so how would you relate dynamic analysis and testing (technique, method)? Lets consider dynamic analysis tools separately. Kinda confusing that dynamic analysis is often called just testing.

Comment: The terminology can be confusing. Manual testing and dynamic program analysis are related in that they are both quality assurance efforts and in that they depend on executing the program to work, but as I said above, they each achieve goals that the other could not.

Comment: Well, another confusion..isnt that Quality control? I so hate this subject..

Comment: I believe "quality control" refers to efforts to ensure a consistent level of quality in a production line, and it has an industrial connotation. "Quality assurance" is more commonly used in software development. I hope your reviewers don't get too caught up on this---at that level it's mostly splitting hairs, in my opinion.

Comment: The thing is that many SQA books do distinct between QC and QA. QC is often considered to be testing, but it depends on the author.

Comment: Yes. In general, I don't think it's profitable to waste too much time on this distinction (unless you have an academic field to carve out).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a bit academic. And I still cannot say how dynamic analysis and testing is related. The closest thing would be that testing is a form of DA.

Comment: As I've said, dynamic analysis and testing are related in that they are both QA efforts and in that both rely on the execution of code. Other than that, they're different in every way. For example, and as my response already indicates, dynamic analysis is concerned with issues of profiling, memory usage, and coverage, while testing is concerned with more mundane smoke tests, usability, etc.

Comment: That is the problem, many sources put = between these. E.g. that running a test is dynamic analysis of a code as you execute it.

Comment: I don't know what sources would these be, but they're misguided.

Comment: Actually almost every book I can view on google books says so. I would need a reference if you say it is not like that. I would say testing is one of the ways of DA maybe.

Comment: I'm not sure we'll benefit from dragging this any further. Testing is not a form of dynamic analysis, as you yourself have indicated in your edit to this question. If you take "testing" to mean broadly any quality assurance efforts, then of course dynamic analysis is a form of "testing", as are many other things.